# In the photoelectric effect experiment shown in the figure down below, Does the galvanometer only read the photocurrent?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

[image]

Does the galvanometer read the photocurrent only or charges in the native conductor take part in as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the anode and the cathode there is a vacuum, ie no mobile charge carriers are present when no light is shone on the apparatus.

The galvanometer measures the current (net charge per second) passing though it and that is the same current (net charge per second) flowing between the anode and the cathode as the gap between the anode and the cathode and the galvanometer are in series.

Answer (score 0):

Electric current flows in circles: that's why we call a thing like this a "circuit". In this case, current is free to flow through the conductor, but the current through the phototube is limited by the illumination, so the phototube controls the current flow around the circuit. The mobility of the charges in the conductor is too high for them to significantly limit the current, so you may forget them in your model.